# Volley onErrorResponse not called

Tags: android, request, android-volley

in my `parseNetworkResponse` method, sometimes I get an exception which should be caught and run `return Response.error(new ParseError(e));`

this happens, but ultimately my `onErrorResponse` method is never called, and I'm not sure how  to branch logic to alter my views in case of an error, since my UI thread never gets to this case.

is anyone familiar with this issue (as opposed to me posting my entire class and trying to see if you can analyze this issue with just that)...  perhaps there are some key classes I need to extend from Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is that your extended Request class has to also implement deliverError, along with deliverResponse

```
private final Listener<T> mListener;
private ErrorListener mErrorListener;

@Override
 public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
}
```

with `ErrorListener` initialized in your constructor